# Poorly defined tag, "mitigation"

Tags: discussion, tags, useless-tags

I see a newly created tag, [mitigation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mitigation) created just a short while ago. It seems to me that it's got far too narrow a scope (kernel exploits).

I couldn't see anywhere to flag the tag itself for (re)consideration.

Is it appropriate?

Comment: On a site that's not dedicated to security, I imagine our existing [tag:security] tag would cover it.

Comment: We also have [tag:vulnerability], which seems tightly related. From both the areas-of-expertise and the practical tag usage points of view they may even be synonyms - if only they weren't so semantically distant from each other...

Comment: Tag's gone now, since it was removed from the only post that had it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest this procedure:

1. If the tag is used on sufficiently few<sup>1</sup> questions, then

   1. If you are sufficiently sure<sup>1</sup>
      that the tag doesn’t belong on our site,
      simply edit all the questions where it is used, and remove it. 
      (If possible, replace it with a more appropriate tag.) 
      This will cause the tag to be deleted if it is not used again
      within six to eight croptings
      (where a cropting<sup>2</sup> is approximately 3½ hours).
   2. If you are sufficiently sure<sup>1</sup>
      that the tag belongs on our site, but is defined incorrectly, then

      - Edit the tag to improve its definition.
      - If the tag is not used on any question where it is appropriate,
        based on its new definition (written by you),
        find at least one such question and add the tag.
      - Remove the tag from all questions where it is inappropriately used.
2. If the above doesn’t resolve the problem, post to Meta.

____________
<sup>1</sup> Yes, these are subjective determinations.
<sup>2</sup> Nonsense word generated by http://soybomb.com/tricks/words/.

Comment: Disclosure: The “mitigation” tag was used on only one question. ***I*** removed it from that question. Then, unlike your typical James Bond villain, I stood by and sadistically watched it die.